# Bower registration ignores .bowerrc's register value

Tags: bower

I've setup a simple bower project with the following ".bowerrc"-file in the project directory:

```
{
  "directory": "app/bower_components",
  "register": "http://1.1.1.1:1337/nexus/repository/TestBower/"
}
```

I use the following command to register the package to my repository:

```
bower register bowertestcomponent http://user@myBitbucket.a.b.c:1337/scm/btc/bowertestcomponent.git
```

The output is as follows:

```
bower bowertestcomponent#*     resolve http://user@myBitbucket.a.b.c:1337/scm/btc/bowertestcomponent.git#*
bower bowertestcomponent#*    checkout master
bower bowertestcomponent#*    resolved http://user@myBitbucket.a.b.c:1337/scm/btc/bowertestcomponent.git#48c28acc11
? Registering a package will make it installable via the registry (https://bower.herokuapp.com), continue? No
```

Please mention the last line. Instead of using the value given as "register" in the ".bowerrc"-file, bower tries to upload the component to "https://bower.herokuapp.com".

The "bowerrc"-file in my user-profile (the per-user config file) looks like this:

```
{
  "registry" : {
    "search" : [ "http://1.1.1.1:1337/nexus/repository/bower-all/" ]
   },
   "register" : "http://1.1.1.1:1337/nexus/repository/bower-internal/",
  "resolvers" : [ "bower-nexus3-resolver" ],
  "nexus" : {
    "username" : "deploy-user",
    "password" : "aPassword"
  }
}
```

- Git-server: Bitbucket
- Repository-server: Nexus 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your bowerrc is not set up correctly.
In your example you seem to have the "register" value outside of the "registry" object. It should be setup like this though:

```
"registry" : {
  "search" : [ "http://1.1.1.1:1337/nexus/repository/bower-all/" ],
  "register" : "http://1.1.1.1:1337/nexus/repository/bower-internal/"
 },
```

This way bower should be able to find your internal registry when deploying.